# Value of datetime variable is changing between Cypress tests

Tags: cypress

Testing the sign up process. These tests are automated overnight in our pipeline. A new username and email address is created by appending a datetime string onto a string:

```js
    describe('sign up for account 2', () => {
        const dateObject = new Date();
        const time = dateObject.getTime().toString()
        const newUsername = 'Foo'+ (time + 10)
        const email = newUsername + '@example.com'
        it('should submit form for a new account', () => {....
```

I have 2 `describe` blocks. They are very similar, they test the sign up process for the 2 different types of accounts you can sign up with (click button A for account type 1 or click button B for account type 2). Both blocks have 3 tests.

In the 2nd `describe` block the value for the variable `newUsername` is changing between test 1 and test 2 - I know this because I have placed `cy.log(newUsername)` at the beginning middle and end of each test.

For example,in the 2nd `describe` block, at the start, middle and end of test 1

`newUsername =  Foo164129352253810`

But, at the start of test 2

`newUsername = Foo164129353447910`

It as if the Datetime object is being called again? This behaviour is inconsistent with the 1st `describe` block. These blocks, and their sign up process, are literally identical apart from 1 different button being selected. Why isn't this happening in both `describe` blocks?

Comment: Do you have two describe blocks or two it blocks? If you have the code being called twice in two separate describe blocks, the reason they would have different values would be because they're obviously being called twice at different times.

Comment: Two describe blocks, and they have 3 it blocks each. I am expecting the value of the username variable to stay the same throughout a describe block, but it isn't. It changes after the 1st one and then stays the same for the 2nd and 3rd it blocks - this is within the same describe block